# Django filtering with kwargs

Tags: python, django

I have the following code.

```
def alpha(**kwargs):
    q_obj_list = [Q(str(i), kwargs.get(i)) for i in kwargs.keys()]
    reduce(operator.and_, q_obj_list)
    return q_obj_list

q = Elements.objects.all()
q = q.filter(alpha(id=1, is_active=False))
```

For this code I am receiving an error saying TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '**getitem**'. I was intending to replace the below code with this.

```
q = Elements.objects.all()
id = kwargs.get("id")
active = kwargs.get("is_active")
q.filter(id=id,is_active=active)
```

How to I fix such an error ?

Comment: Please change `id = kwargs.get("id)` by `id = kwargs.get("id")`. As it is a very small change I cannot edit your question. What is `Q`?

Comment: Why not simple query? `q = Elements.objects.filter(id=kwargs.get("id"), active=kwargs.get("is_active"))`

Comment: @RomanMindlin I am asking for a better way in cases when the number of fields are large and arguments are optional.

Comment: Ok. What about `q = Elements.objects.filter(**kwargs)`?

Comment: @RomanMindlin The way works fine for me and consider as preferred answer. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:
`q = Elements.objects.filter(**kwargs)`